# Unable to load prophet model in visual studio on my macbook m1 pro, earlier this used work in my windows vs code

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I am unable to load the prophet model in my v code earlier this was working in my windows laptop, it is mainly showing runtime error "RuntimeError: Error during optimization" .thiscode is ruuning fine on google collab also but not on my mac installed vs code and jupyter  As my last transition from windows to mac is showing me some challenges so can somebody help me [i have attache the code iam working in the left and the error popped on the output page in right side of the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvCpL.jpg)

1. i have tried reinstalling prophet model in terminal